# How to change the where column name based on input parameter value?

Tags: sql, oracle

In the below SQL. I am passing the input parameter Job_Owner. It can be 'A' or 'B'  or 'C'. Now if A is passed i have to get

- the distinct bay_gourp for job_owner A
- total count of each bay for job_owner A
- count of bay with  A_assign_date is less than 21 days
- count of bay with A_assign_date between 21 to 28 days
- count of bay with A_assign date greater than 28 days

if the Job Owner is 'B' then fetch the below details

- the distinct bay_gourp for job_owner B
- total count of each bay for job_owner B
- count of bay with  B_assign_date is less than 21 days
- count of bay with B_assign_date between 21 to 28 days
- count of bay with B_assign date greater than 28 days

If i run the SQL for Job_owner A , i am getting the output as below

```
BAY_GROUP | COUNT(*) | AGCOUNT | AYCOUNT| ARCOUNT|BGCOUNT | BYCOUNT| 
Bay1         16        8          5       3       0          0
Bay3          1        1          0       0       0          0

BRCOUNT|CGCOUNT | CYCOUNT| CRCOUNT|
0       0         0        0
0       0         0        0
```

But i want the output as below

```
BAY_GROUP | COUNT(*) | AGCOUNT | AYCOUNT| ARCOUNT
Bay1         16        8          5       3      
Bay3          1        1          0       0
```

---

```
SELECT  BAY_GROUP , COUNT(*),
       sum(case when (JOB_OWNER = 'A' AND A_ASSIGN_DT > sysdate-21) then 1 else 0 end) AGCount,
       sum(case when (JOB_OWNER = 'A' AND (A_ASSIGN_DT < sysdate-21 AND A_ASSIGN_DT > sysdate-28)) then 1 else 0 end) AYCount,
       sum(case when (JOB_OWNER = 'A' AND  A_ASSIGN_DT < sysdate-28) then 1 else 0 end) ARCount,
       sum(case when (JOB_OWNER = 'B' AND B_ASSIGN_DT > sysdate-21) then 1 else 0 end) BGCount,
       sum(case when (JOB_OWNER = 'B' AND (B_ASSIGN_DT > sysdate-21 AND B_ASSIGN_DT > sysdate-28)) then 1 else 0 end) BYCount,
       sum(case when (JOB_OWNER = 'B' AND  B_ASSIGN_DT < sysdate-28) then 1 else 0 end) BRCount,
       sum(case when (JOB_OWNER = 'C' AND C_ASSIGN_DT > sysdate-21) then 1 else 0 end) CGCount,
       sum(case when (JOB_OWNER = 'C' AND (C_ASSIGN_DT < sysdate-21 AND C_ASSIGN_DT > sysdate-28)) then 1 else 0 end) CYCount,
       sum(case when (JOB_OWNER = 'C' AND  C_ASSIGN_DT < sysdate-28) then 1 else 0 end) CRCount
     FROM XX_YY_ZZ WHERE 
                    BAY_GROUP IS NOT NULL
                    AND JOBSTATUS = 'InProcess'
                    AND ORG = '17' 
                    AND JOB_OWNER in ('A')
                     GROUP BY BAY_GROUP
```

Comment: Remove the columns that you don't want ?

Comment: yes. I dont want the select statement to execute for Job Owner 'B' and 'C' when only 'A' is passed.

Comment: @Jan69 If you don't want the column at all, you'll need to use dynamic sql to construct the query.  Unrelated, but you should remove `DISTINCT` from your query.  `GROUP BY` is distinct by its very nature.

Comment: Ok. Removed the DISTINCT keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, this should give you the output for the parametrized `JOB_OWNER`.

```
SELECT JOB_OWNER,BAY_GROUP,COUNT(*),
       sum(case when (A_ASSIGN_DT > sysdate-21) then 1 else 0 end) GCount,
       sum(case when (A_ASSIGN_DT < sysdate-21 AND A_ASSIGN_DT > sysdate-28) then 1 else 0 end) YCount,
       sum(case when (A_ASSIGN_DT < sysdate-28) then 1 else 0 end) RCount
     FROM XX_YY_ZZ WHERE 
                    BAY_GROUP IS NOT NULL
                    AND JOBSTATUS = 'InProcess'
                    AND ORG = '17' 
                    AND JOB_OWNER in ('A')
                     GROUP BY JOB_OWNER,BAY_GROUP
```

The only difference is that the parameter will be the first column instead of the column prefix, if you can live with that.